# pass a variable from python script to wix project

Tags: python-2.7, wix

I have python script which has a setting window where the user can select the installation path for installing the software and i have a wix project for my app which can be build using msbuild. My question is, How can i pass the selected path from the setting window of my script to the source path of my wix components?The selected path is stored in a variable 'x' as well as written in the registry.Either i have to pass the variable 'x' from the script to wix or from registry to wix. Please help me out.My wix code looks like below,

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="Companyname" >
                <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="myapp">
                    <Component Id='MainExecutable' Guid='*'>
                    <File Id='ExecutableFile' Name='mv.exe' DiskId='1' Source='c:\myfolder\...\qv.exe' KeyPath='yes'/>
                    </Component>
```

The path in the 'Source' should be from python script(from variable or registry) .

Answer (score 2):

Because that is a file path, you have a couple options.

1. (my favorite) Use `bind paths` - if you use a relative path in the `File/@Source` attribute or you can use explicit named bind path syntax that looks like `!(bindpath.VarName)` then you can provide one or more bind paths via the command line to `light.exe` using the `-bp` switch (multiple times, if you wish).
2. Use `preprocessor variable` - you can use `File Source='$(var.VarName)'` and provide a value for `$(var.VarName)` by passing the `-d` command-line switch to `candle.exe`.  For example, your python script could prompt the user for the source location of the qv.exe file then pass the result to the build doing `candle -dVarName="python_variable_value_goes_here"`. It's just a preprocessor variable in the end.

I prefer #1 because it allows me to search for the executable on multiple ordered paths that may change at link time. Using a preprocessor variable locks the path in during compile time.

Comment: Thank you @ROb. Since my project is on automating the build process, your suggestion may not work.I cannot hardcode the path in wix.I should get the path from setting window of my script which varies whenever user changes it.Can i get the path from the registry and pass it to 'source'path??

Comment: I'm confused. the `Source` path is defined at build time, not at install time. Are you asking how to set the install path?

Comment: I am asking about the source path.what you mentioned above is correct. What if the source path is changed by the user(assuming source path is  of some installed software)? Does wix detects it and changes it?

Comment: No, there is nothing in the WiX build process that will search for a file on your machine to include in the MSI. This is a rather unusual thing to do. :) Your python script (or something) would need to find the location of the file and pass it into the build of the WiX toolset.

Comment: I am sorry if i am not clear.I want the source path to be under user control. It should be read from the GUI of my python script.

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your last question. A preprocessor variable will work just fine for you.

Comment: ohh ok!! thanks @Rob. Btw, Can i read values from the registry(it has the needed path) and pass it to 'source' path in wix??

Comment: Yes, your python script could read the registry and pass the value in.

Comment: ok.I know to read the values from registry in python. the only thing is i have to learn is how to pass those values to source path in wix.Thank you @Rob Mensching for ur valuable information.